# Find main.tex file in parent folder when using latexmk

Tags: compiling, latexmk

I have the following file structure for my document:

```
document
├── acronym.tex
├── bibliography.bib
├── chapters
│   ├── some-chapter.tex
│   └── another-chapter.tex
├── figures
│   ├── some-figure.pdf
│   └── another-figure.pdf
└── main.tex
```

Now I want to open a file in the chapters folder and (inside the text editor) run a command to compile the whole document.

If I try to run `latexmk -pdf` or `latexmk -pdf some-chapter` inside the chapters folder I get a ton of error messages because latexmk doesn't know about the main.tex.

Is there a way to tell latexmk that it should also look in the parent folder? Or somehow declare the main.tex as main file?

I tried `latexmk -pdf ../main` (which anyways would not be satifying) but then I get `! LaTeX Error: File`acronym.tex' not found.`

So far I had a `main.tex.latexmain` file in the document folder and vim-latex was able to find the main in the parent folder (see the [vim-latex documentation](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-project.html)). A similar solution with latexmk would be perfect.

Comment: Have you tried to put `% !TeX root = main.tex` as the first line of your main.tex ?

Comment: Does adding a `-cd` option help?  I.e., try using the command line `latexmk -cd -pdf ../main`

Comment: Thank you for your comments @JohnCollins and Jérôme! I've tried the !Tex one before and it didn't seem to have any effect. The `-cd` option indeed works! I'll now somehow have to figure out how to set the file path because I want to write a shortcut for the compiling and of course it won't always be "../main". Anyways, thank you a lot!